# How to get table cell values any where in the table using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the following table that returns the each cell value when clicked using javascript?

How can i do the same using jquery?

```
 <script language="javascript">

        var tbl = document.getElementById("tblMain");
        if (tbl != null) {
            for (var i = 0; i < tbl.rows.length; i++) {
                for (var j = 0; j < tbl.rows[i].cells.length; j++)
                    tbl.rows[i].cells[j].onclick = function () { getval(this); };
            }
        }

        function getval(cel) {
            alert(cel.innerHTML);
        }
    </script>

<table align="center" id="tblMain" border="1" style="cursor: pointer;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                R1C1
            </td>
            <td>
                R1C2
            </td>
            <td>
                R1C3
            </td>
            <td>
                R1C4
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                R2C1
            </td>
            <td>
                R2C2
            </td>
            <td>
                R2C3
            </td>
            <td>
                R2C4
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                R3C1
            </td>
            <td>
                R3C2
            </td>
            <td>
                R3C3
            </td>
            <td>
                R3C4
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                R4C1
            </td>
            <td>
                R4C2
            </td>
            <td>
                R4C3
            </td>
            <td>
                R4C4
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#tblMain').find('td').click(function(){
   alert($(this).text());
});
```

Living demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pf5cL/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
   $('#tblMain td').click(function() {
       alert($(this).html()); // or .text()
   });
});
```

jQuery will internally iterate through all the cells for you, so you don't need any looping code at all.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$("#tblMain tr td").click(function() {
    var content = $(this).text();
    console.log(content); //Cell text
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var getval = function(html) {
    alert(html);
  }

  $('#tblMain td').on('click', function(){
    getval($(this).html());
  });
});
```

Comment: Use `.on()` instead of `.bind()`. Or just `.click()`.