# jQuery - Get table cell value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table which looks like the following. The price normally comes from a database this is just for showing the problem I have.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).delegate('.amount input[type="text"]','keyup',(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var sub_total = $this.find('.sub_total');
        var price = $this.find('.price').text();
        var amount = $this.val();
        alert(price);
    }));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="tickets" id="tickets" class="amount" maxlength="2" autocomplete="off"></td>
      <td>Ticket:</td>
      <td class="price">20,50</td>
      <td class="sub_total"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

What I would like to do is: when the user types a number in the field `tickets` it should update the field `sub_total`. With the jQuery I have this is not working. When I `alert(price)` I get `undefined`. So I wonder how to make the `sub_total` field with auto updated values. It might also be interesting to know that I have more rows like this beneath this row. So the script should only update the field from one specific row at a time.

What I already tried but without success:
[How to get a table cell value using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612128/how-to-get-a-table-cell-value-using-jquery);
[How to get a table cell value using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376081/how-to-get-a-table-cell-value-using-jquery);
[How to get table cell values any where in the table using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18874185/how-to-get-table-cell-values-any-where-in-the-table-using-jquery)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `'input[type="text"].amount'` instead of `'.amount input[type="text"]'` notice space is removed

Comment: And you should use `on()` instead of `delegate()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do traverse back up to the parent tr element before you try to find the .sub_title or .price elements.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).delegate('.amount input[type="text"]','keyup',(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var $tr = $this.closest("tr");
        var sub_total = $tr.find('.sub_total');
        var price = $tr.find('.price').text();
        var amount = $this.val();
        alert(price);
    }));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change you code like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('input[type="text"].amount', 'keyup', (function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var sub_total = $this.closest("tr").find('.sub_total');
        var price = $this.closest("tr").find('.price').text();
        var amount = $this.val();
        alert(price);
    }));
});
```

`find()` will search for the children. So you should get into the parent `tr` first before using `find()`.

You can use `closest("tr")` to get the parent `tr` element

Answer (score 0):

It's because `price` and `sub_total` are not children of the current element (as [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) is selecting):

```
var sub_total = $this.find('.sub_total');
var price = $this.find('.price').text();
```

they are siblings of its parent or more simply children of the container `tr`.

Try instead:

```
var sub_total = $this.closest('tr').find('.sub_total');
var price = $this.closest('tr').find('.price').text();
```

Answer (score -1):

example for a

```
<table id="#myTable">
```

I write this:

```
function setCell( idTab, row, col, text) {
  var idCel = idTab + " tbody tr:nth-child(" + row + ") td:nth-child(" + col + ")";
  $(idCel).html(text);
}

function getCell( idTab, row, col ) {
  var idCel =idTab + " tbody tr:nth-child(" + row + ") td:nth-child(" + col + ")";
  return $(idCel).html();
}

setCell( "#myTab", 3, 4, "new value" );
alert( getCell("#myTab", 3, 4);
```

Comment: As you can see the question is already 2 years old and was already answered then. These functions also aren't general enough to solve the problem I had.